# Updating for each row in a table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have this query here which returns an error because of too many rows returned:

```
UPDATE tmp_rsl2 SET comm_percent=( SELECT c2.comm_percent
FROM tmp_rsl2 t1 
INNER JOIN gn_salesperson g1 ON t1.sales_person=g1.sales_person
INNER JOIN comm_schema c1 ON g1.comm_schema=c1.comm_schema
INNER JOIN comm_schema_dt c2 ON c1.comm_schema_id=c2.comm_schema_id AND (t1.balance_amount::numeric <= (COALESCE(c2.value_amount,0)) );`
```

Basically for each row of the `comm_percent` column, I want to update all of them using the subquery `SELECT` statement. I imagine using a `FOR loop` or something but I'd like to hear ideas or to know a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `TOO_MANY_ROWS` is about assigning a value to a variable, that can only take '1' (one) value, whereas the SELECT query is returning [more than one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Without a reference schema, its difficult to give an `SQL` that'd work (not to say that the issue lies with the `Schema`), but you need to ensure that the value assigned to `comm_percent` from the `SELECT` statement returns only 1 row. A very blind attempt at how it 'might' work in your case (given below), but again without knowing the schema its difficult to gauge whether it'd work.

```
UPDATE tmp_rsl2
SET comm_percent = c2.comm_percent
FROM gn_salesperson g1 ON 
  INNER JOIN comm_schema c1 ON g1.comm_schema = c1.comm_schema
  INNER JOIN comm_schema_dt c2 ON c1.comm_schema_id = c2.comm_schema_id
    AND (tmp_rsl2.balance_amount::NUMERIC <= (COALESCE(c2.value_amount, 0)))
WHERE tmp_rsl2.sales_person = g1.sales_person
```

**UPDATE**

As per below comments, have given an unrelated SQLFiddle [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/81b93/4) that should give an idea of how to perform an `UPDATE` of *all* rows of a table looking up corresponding values from another table.

Comment: I'm not trying to insert 1 data only, I'm trying to insert all those rows (from the SELECT subquery) and update each row (which would have different values).

Comment: I thinking about using a FOR statement to loop for total amount of rows found in the subquery and update column where conditions meet, is there a workaround for this matter or something?

Comment: Without Schema its difficult to arrive at the correct query. Have updated SQL that would *try* to update all rows of the base table, but again it may or may not work as expected.

Comment: Its not a problem with the schema, lets say I have `tbl_a` which has a column that lists the letters from `a-z`, then `tbl_b` would have a column with the order values `1-26`. So the question is, how to update each row in `tbl_a` to have the values `1-26` from `tbl_b`. Btw, I tried your query, it only takes the first row of `tbl_b` which is 1 & makes all the rows in `tbl_a` become 1.  I want `tbl_a` to have values `1-26`

Comment: if I could type values 1,2,3... until 26, I would do that but the problem is that the `comm_percent` value is not predictable.

Comment: Just created an unrelated SQLFiddle example that should give an idea of how to perform an *UPDATE* of all rows of a table looking up corresponding values from another table.

Comment: Just checked your SQLFiddle example, it still doesn't work on my query. You see, mine doesn't have the WHERE clause. Consider something like: `update tbl_a
set n = tbl_b.n
FROM tbl_b;` It would result in all rows turning into 1.

Comment: As mentioned, it was an unrelated Query to only show the usage of `UPDATE`. Without more input I doubt many would be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your time answering my questions, I think I'll try to add a serial column for table entries, so I could just use it for my WHERE clause.